# Powershell mount-diskimage -imagepath, "The system cannot find the file specified."

Tags: powershell

I am creating a bootable ISO, part of this is mounting an ISO which has been working fine.  At some stage in the development I have created a problem which I cannot see how or what the issue is.

I am running an instance of "Administrator: Deployment and Imaging Tools Environment"

When I execute:

```
powershell Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath 'C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216/W10-LTSB.iso'
```

This was working, but it now results in:

```
Mount-DiskImage : The system cannot find the file specified.
At line:1 char:1
+ Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath 'C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-Opera ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CatergoryInfo         : ObjectNotFound: (MSFT_DiskImage:ROOT/Microsoft/.../MSFT_DiskImage) [Mount-DiskImage], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070002,Mount-DiskImage
```

I can mount the ISO using Explorer, right clicking on the ISO and selecting Mount, but I need this to work from the command line.

Comment: Why are there both forward slashes and backward slashes in the file path?

Comment: @Dave.d, no idea, will take a look and try changing to be consistent.

Comment: @Dave.d, all using backslash, still same problem.

Comment: Where do you execute `powershell Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath 'C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216/W10-LTSB.iso'
` , in cmd? or?

Comment: I've tried both a cmd elevated to Administrator and also Administrator deployment and imaging environment shell.

Comment: Not sure about the other shell you were referring to, but in `cmd` I believe that's not the correct syntax. Should be something like `powershell -command "Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath 'C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216/W10-LTSB.iso'" `

Comment: @Dave.d, tried it and exactly the same response.

Comment: @Dave.d, I've even tried going into powershell and trying the command, same error.

Comment: Try moving the file out of a protected folder like c:\users\username to something like c:\isofiles

Comment: @Silbee, I don't believe this is the problem as I have full access to that folder, I am the use and I'm running as Adminstrator, also it did work earlier this morning, so whatever is causing the problem is something new.

Comment: @Silbee, that all said, I just tried it and it works...so what has changed that is now causing this to be a problem?

Comment: what happens if you do `dir C:\Users\u49100\Downloads\CA20-4002-OperatingSystem-AIMB-216/W10-LTSB.iso` from your cmd window?

Comment: Doh, I've been looking at this for hours and I must have messed up the path, its ok now, thank you Dave.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was caused by an incorrect file path